What makes a good motivator?
Are there any Torah sources for what would make something a good motivator for children? i.e. are there some that are more sustainable or more productive than others?

I don't know about it being good, sustainable or productive in practice, but in Rambam's introduction to his commentary on Mishnah Sanhedrin 10, there's a description of how one would go about enticing a young child to learn Torah, and sustaining his motivation as he grows older, and his desires and goals mature.

This answer applies mainly to older children/young adults who are more capable of reason, however it can apply to younger children as well. There are 2 parts.
First off, The Mishna in Avos (4:2).
בן עזאי אומר הוי רץ למצוה קלה ובורח מן העבירה שמצוה גוררת מצוה ועברה גוררת עברה ששכר מצוה מצוה ושכר עברה עברה
Ben Azai says, “Run toward a light mitzvah and flee from an aveirah, for a mitzvah leads to a mitzvah, and an aveirah leads to an aveirah; for the reward of a mitzvah is a mitzvah, and the reward of an aveirah is an aveirah.
The idea of mitzvah goreres mitzvah is not merely some magical concept you learnt as a kid, it’s a fact of human nature and one of the greatest motivators.
If someone does an act that appeals to his better self, he will immediately feel a sense of pride and accomplishment, thus causing him to want to experience that feeling again. The reason we fail to do what we truly want is due to fear, and this positive experience gives him the confidence to reach higher in spite of that fear. This is mitzvah goreres mitzvah on an adult level, and is why we “force” children to do certain things as part of chinuch; we shove a good feeling down their throat so they have the taste in their mouth.
The second, and more important thing, is parents. I’m not going to list Torah sources for this because A) there aren’t any explicit ones that I can think off the top of my head, although there are countless ones by way of inference, and B) it’s purely common sense which is the best source.
Parents are the greatest motivators. Not with what they tell their children to try to motivate them, but rather by how they act as people themselves.
A child’s nature is to want to emulate his or her parents. Part of the reason we refer to Hashem as Avinu Malkeinu, is because those are the 2 ultimate beings that are naturally revered. A subject naturally reveres a king, and a child naturally reveres a parent. One might even say a child idolizes a parent.
However, this natural state cannot be abused. If a parent lives a way of life that he or she is not proud of, the child will inevitably become aware of that fact whether consciously or not, and just like that there’s a crack in the child’s admiration of his parents. He’s no longer so confident that his daddy is “the man”. At that point the will to emulate his father starts to dissipate.
It’s a difficult pill to swallow, but most of the time when our children are failing in an area, it’s our fault. Kids that are confident in their parents (who are confident in themselves) are nearly untouchable. You can’t shake them because they come home everyday to their “idol” who’s the man, and that’s who they emulate and they want nothing more than to make their father proud and be just like him.
There’s no greater motivation for a child than giving them a true role model.
Hope this helps.

I saw once in a book on parenting advice pruned from the lectures of HaRav Pinchas Sheinberg Z'tl, where he recommended "positive jealousy". Instead of making examples of bad behaviour, make examples of good behaviour.

E.g. when one child does something very good, try to make the others "jealous" of how well that child did by letting them see how you praise and reward him.

I'm sure this advice would raise some "red flags" by some people (generally, the ones who tend to use the phrase "red flag" a lot), but it's still better than shaming children who do badly, which is what most parents' natural instinct is to do.

IIRC the book was "Heart to heart talks: Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg : lectures to women". I am not a woman, but read it anyway. Don't judge.

is that referrring to the concept of creating kinas sofrim ie a culture where we look up to those who are better than us?
